# Can a client make a request with RestTemplate without a certificate to a secure SSL server?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, https, resttemplate

could somebody please help me with the following questions:

I have a REST server that has SSL enabled and a REST client that are on 2 different computers. Both are built with Spring boot. The server will have a .p12 or .pfx certificate.

If the REST client wants to make a request to the server, does it need to provide a certificate or can it make a request with a simple RestTemplate even if the server is secure? Does the same rules apply for Postman or can Postman send a request without a certificate as well?

I tried to create a request from the REST client, using a REST template with the certificate. But I am not sure, which certificate should I provide. Should it be the same certificate that is on the server or another one? And does the certificate from the server need to have a rule for the ip of the REST client to allow the requests?

The ssl server configuration:

```
ssl:
 key-store-type: PKCS12
 key-store: ${MY_DIR}/config/ssl/myCert.pfx
 key-store-password: 123456
```

The rest template from the client:

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = null;
    try {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
            .create()
            .loadTrustMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:config/ssl/myCert.pfx"), password.toCharArray())
            .build();

        HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLContext(sslContext)
            .build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(client);

        restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | KeyManagementException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Error getting the RestTemplate with ssl certificate", ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If a client certificate is required or not depends fully on the server configuration. Some servers require client certificates, some do not. Please refer to the documentation of your specific REST API to find out what the requirements on the client are.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                        .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
                        .build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
                        new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

please use this below import packages.

```
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts;
import org.apache.http.ssl.TrustStrategy;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
```